# Priority is the ones vs priority are the ones?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

A - Top priority are the ones you already know.

B - Top priority is the ones you already know.

C - Top priorities are the ones you already know.

Is A correct or B?

I'm inclined towards A.

I think C is correct.

Comment: It really depends on whether "the ones you already know" represents a coherent group sharing "top priority" status. It's fine to say something like *Our top priority right now is the victims. We''ll worry about stranded tourists later.*

Comment: The ones you already know are a top priority. A top priority are the ones  you already know.

Answer (score 0):

**A and B are both incorrect because they mix tenses.**

> Top priority (singular) *are the ones* (plural) you already know.
>
> Top priority is (singular) *the ones* (plural) you already know.

C is almost correct, but you are missing the word "the":

> **The top priorities** are the ones you already know.

Answer (score 0):

A & B are both incorrect. C is correct. A/B describe a single priority, therefore:

> Top priority is the one you already know.

Answer (score 0):

A is correct if "the ones you already know" means a group of things that are not the priorities.

A is incorrect if "the ones you already know" means the priorities, because Priority would need to be plural.

B is incorrect because 'is' should be paired with a singular priority.

C is correct but it could mean two things just like A.